# Google Fonts API usage in an ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, google-fonts

I'm building a web application using ASP.NET Core. For font styling I used the Google Fonts API. I included some code in the head section of the `_layout.cshtml` file.

Locally the API is working perfectly, I know this because I tried fonts which are not installed on my machine. However when I publish my app to Hosting website, the default font is rendered

How can I solve this issue?

This is what I've tried

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200..1000&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Radwan, where did you host? Some hosting providers might have specific settings or configurations that affect how external resources like fonts are loaded. Besides, have you tried test in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
When publish this code on IIS site works.

Check if your server accept googleapis and gstatic request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200..1000&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cairo Test</h1>
    <p>Hello world.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2:**

Comments:

- Remove `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">`, `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>` I recommend to delete `":wght@200..1000"` because in body section you can setup the font width .

Also, try using font-family with single single quote

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: 'Cairo',sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cairo Test</h1>
    <p>Hello world.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 3**

Just for discard default style on Plesk/Net Core/CSS Boostrap add !important.

```
body 
{
   font-family: 'Cairo',sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the same code that I used, I just didn't include the full version.
but the question is: how can I googles-is and gstatic, I'm noob in using servers

Comment: Ok, Can you tell me which server or hosting you use to host your site?

Comment: Please, try to use my 2nd Edit hope this works.

Comment: @BlackSD different font weights use different font files... so if you remove the weights you won't download the correct font files

Comment: @zgood You're right but in some cases browsers show an error while loading the url when using 200..1000 by the ellipsis. I wanna think that's why doesnt show the font.

Comment: *browsers show an error while loading the url when using 200..1000 by the ellipsis*  If you encountered issues in this regards it had other reasons (e.g bad IIS mime defaults ). As commented by @zgood: you definitely need to specify weights - otherwise you get only font-face rules for regular.

Comment: @BlackSD I'm using a local hosting service called LibyanSpider but the control panel is Plesk. I'll use your second approach and give you feedback

Comment: @MohammadRadwan Got it, now try the 3rd Edit just for discard default style on each platform, I search information about Plesk policies and they don't have any problem with Google font, Are you check the browser debug console ?

Comment: @MohammadRadwan Hi, Did any solution work for you?